# Failed to allocate huge images in OpenCV

Tags: image, memory-management, opencv

I'm working since a year on image processing with OpenCV 2.2.0.

I get a memory allocation error ONLY if I try to allocate a >2GB IplImage, given that the same allocation with CvMat works. I can allocate whatever I want using CvMat, I tried also >10 GB.

OpenCV was 64-bit compiled and also this simple application. Furthermore, I'm sure that the application runs in 64-bit mode as I can see from the Task Manager. The O.S. (Windows 7) is 64-bit too.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    printf("trying to allocate >2GB matrix...\n");
    CvMat *huge_matrix = cvCreateMat(40000,30000,CV_16UC1);
    cvSet(huge_matrix,cvScalar(5));
    printf("...done!\n\n");
    system("PAUSE");

    printf("trying to allocate >2GB image...\n");
    IplImage *huge_img = cvCreateImage(cvSize(40000,30000),IPL_DEPTH_16U, 1);
    cvSet(huge_img,cvScalar(5));
    printf("...done!\n\n");
    system("PAUSE");

    cvReleaseMat(&huge_matrix);
    cvReleaseImage(&huge_img);
}
```

The error message is "Insufficient memory:  in unknown function... can it be a bug?

Answer (score 2):

`IplImage` structure does not support images bigger then 2Gb because it stores total image size in the field of `int` type. Even if you allocate `IplImage` bigger then 2Gb with some hack then other methods will not be able to process it correctly. OpenCV inherited `IplImage` structure from the Intel Image Processing Library so there are no chance that format will be changed.

You should use newer structures (`CvMat` in C interface or `cv::Mat` in C++ interface) to operate with huge images.